# Is there a system monitoring tool that lets me write complex queries against the data?

Tags: monitoring, statistics

I am looking for a system stat collection tool that will let me write queries against the data collected. I am planning to answer questions like:

- what is the average load, over the last 30 days, on this machine between 9AM and 5PM, as opposed to at night
- what was the average disk io on these 10 machines yesterday
- what was the average daytime memory usage on these 10 machines last week, as opposed to 2 weeks ago

Has anyone done this with, say, collectd or graphite?

Answer (score 1):

Are you restricting this to a bespoke system? Or would you consider an existing service? I wouldn't say that the examples you have given are complex queries.

Existing services such as: monitor.us, newrelic.com and many others offer the kinds of statistics you are after.

If you want to run your own thing, services such as prtg or Nagios will capture the data in a way that can be analysed.

Alernatively, you could simply run a script on a CRON timer that appended data to a CSV file and analyse that with Excel.